# How to load the json result from pkfare api to html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, api

The scenario is the customer searches for the fights by giving source, destination and date which will call the api

the below json is the result recieved from the api call, actually the data is very huge i reduced the content length,
My question is how to bring this json to html accordingly. I'm new to this and really need help.

The format of result i'm expecting:-

**Source | Destination | Flight no. | Flight time | price | etc**

I've got this result as per the documentation in http://open.pkfare.com/documents/show, i googled for this but i didn't get any result.

```
{
  "errorCode": "0",
  "errorMsg": "ok",
  "data": {
    "searchKey": "HKGSIN20180930Y3000",
    "shoppingKey": "cache-e22f3a7c64a8441aae3eb963b8f1c3ad",
    "solutions": [
      {
        "solutionKey": "513a4a345f4876bee42f5efed77540c6",
        "solutionId": "39978959411036278",
        "fareType": "PUBLIC",
        "currency": "USD",
        "adtFare": 2728.950,
        "adtTax": 111.230,
        "chdFare": 0,
        "chdTax": 0,
        "chnFare": 0,
        "chnTax": 0,
        "infFare": 0,
        "infTax": 0,
        "qCharge": 0,
        "tktFee": 0.000,
        "platformServiceFee": 0,
        "comments": null,
        "journeys": {
          "journey_0": [
            "2452fb233079cf2d202bc2690c477120"
          ]
        },
        "fareRule": null,
        "rule": null,
        "platingCarrier": "NH",
        "prices": null,
        "merchantFee": 0.00,
        "baggageMap": {
          "ADT": [
            {
              "segmentIndexList": [
                1,
                2
              ],
              "baggageAmount": "2PC",
              "baggageWeight": null,
              "carryOnAmount": null,
              "carryOnWeight": null
            }
          ]
        },
        "afterSaleRule": null
      },
      {
        "solutionKey": "c85ac13d8786f1a39dac5a96f6d3f19f",
        "solutionId": "39978959392161809",
        "fareType": "PRIVATE",
        "currency": "USD",
        "adtFare": 435.460,
        "adtTax": 74.190,
        "chdFare": 0,
        "chdTax": 0,
        "chnFare": 0,
        "chnTax": 0,
        "infFare": 0,
        "infTax": 0,
        "qCharge": 0,
        "tktFee": 0.000,
        "platformServiceFee": 0,
        "comments": null,
        "journeys": {
          "journey_0": [
            "9f95605e7a8914cafc265468b4454043"
          ]
        },
        "fareRule": null,
        "rule": null,
        "platingCarrier": "PG",
        "prices": null,
        "merchantFee": 0.00,
        "baggageMap": {
          "ADT": [
            {
              "segmentIndexList": [
                1,
                2
              ],
              "baggageAmount": null,
              "baggageWeight": "30kg",
              "carryOnAmount": null,
              "carryOnWeight": null
            }
          ]
        },
        "afterSaleRule": null
      }
    ],
    "flights": [
      {
        "flightId": "3c173c602453148f509106c400db0d5e",
        "journeyTime": 295,
        "transferCount": 1,
        "lastTktTime": null,
        "segmengtIds": [
          "934be0e092612360e8b1a7a34c3feb9c",
          "9b1fbd2e64e6d91d95321c7c7ccfc163"
        ]
      },
      {
        "flightId": "3b47f71bae7a14f05be94fb2a3e04f57",
        "journeyTime": 455,
        "transferCount": 1,
        "lastTktTime": null,
        "segmengtIds": [
          "0fa399295385e4d85ef5f66fd038088b",
          "eab479de38a0911804b1843c93fbdb22"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "segments": [
      {
        "segmentId": "e7752cb33582f1a486e76771c4ff633a",
        "airline": "KA",
        "flightNum": "691",
        "equipment": "333",
        "cabinClass": "ECONOMY",
        "bookingCode": "Y",
        "availabilityCount": 9,
        "departure": "HKG",
        "arrival": "PEN",
        "departureTerminal": "1",
        "arrivalTerminal": null,
        "departureDate": 1538291400000,
        "arrivalDate": 1538304900000,
        "flightTime": 225,
        "stayTime": null,
        "codeShare": "N",
        "opFltNo": null,
        "opFltAirline": null,
        "stopover": null,
        "strDepartureDate": "2018-09-30",
        "strDepartureTime": "15:10",
        "strArrivalDate": "2018-09-30",
        "strArrivalTime": "18:55"
      },
      {
        "segmentId": "8a78bcf0f9e00a151979fadb58897b44",
        "airline": "MU",
        "flightNum": "508",
        "equipment": "321",
        "cabinClass": "ECONOMY",
        "bookingCode": "B",
        "availabilityCount": 9,
        "departure": "HKG",
        "arrival": "PVG",
        "departureTerminal": "1",
        "arrivalTerminal": "1",
        "departureDate": 1538291100000,
        "arrivalDate": 1538301600000,
        "flightTime": 175,
        "stayTime": null,
        "codeShare": "N",
        "opFltNo": null,
        "opFltAirline": null,
        "stopover": null,
        "strDepartureDate": "2018-09-30",
        "strDepartureTime": "15:05",
        "strArrivalDate": "2018-09-30",
        "strArrivalTime": "18:00"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Solution:** Multiple solutions with corresponding prices are displayed.
**Journey:** Each solution includes Journeys. One way trip only includes a Journey_0 in Journeys and round trip includes both Journey_0(outbound) and Journey_1(inbound). Open Jaw includes both Journey_0(first journey) and Journey_1(second journey). The keys in Journey_0 or Journey_1 correspond to FlightId in Flights.
**Flight**：Describes the relationship between Journey and Segment.

I'm expecting code something like this, where the data regarding flight are available

```
        $.each(itineraries, function( itineraryKey, itineraryVal ){
            var inbound          = app.getObjects( legs, 'Id', itineraryVal.InboundLegId),
                inDepartureTime = inbound[0].Departure,
                inArrivalTime   = inbound[0].Arrival,
                inDepartureDate = inbound[0].Departure,
                inArrivalDate   = inbound[0].Arrival,
                inOrigin        = app.getObjects( places, 'Id', inbound[0].DestinationStation),
                inDestination   = app.getObjects( places, 'Id', inbound[0].OriginStation),
                inCarriers      = app.getObjects( carriers, 'Id', inbound[0].OperatingCarriers[0]);

            var outbound         = app.getObjects( legs, 'Id', itineraryVal.OutboundLegId),
                outDepartureTime = outbound[0].Departure,
                outArrivalTime   = outbound[0].Arrival,
                outDepartureDate = outbound[0].Departure,
                outArrivalDate   = outbound[0].Arrival,
                outOrigin        = app.getObjects( places, 'Id', outbound[0].DestinationStation),
                outDestination   = app.getObjects( places, 'Id', outbound[0].OriginStation),
                outCarriers      = app.getObjects( carriers, 'Id', outbound[0].OperatingCarriers[0]);


            var agent     = app.getObjects( agents, 'Id', itineraryVal.PricingOptions[0].Agents[0]);
            var price     = itineraryVal.PricingOptions[0].Price.toFixed(2);
            var permalink = itineraryVal.PricingOptions[0].DeeplinkUrl;
            var time      = itineraryVal.PricingOptions[0].QuoteAgeInMinutes;

            // NEW FORMAT OF DATA
            var data = {
                agent     : agent,
                price     : price,
                time      : time,
                permalink : permalink,
                inbound    : {
                    time : {
                        departure : inDepartureTime,
                        arrival   : inArrivalTime
                    },
                    date : {
                        departure : inDepartureDate,
                        arrival   : inArrivalDate
                    },
                    station : {
                        origin      : inOrigin,
                        destination : inDestination
                    },
                    carriers : inCarriers
                },
                outbound  : {
                    time : {
                        departure : outDepartureTime,
                        arrival   : outArrivalTime
                    },
                    date : {
                        departure : outDepartureDate,
                        arrival   : outArrivalDate
                    },
                    station : {
                        origin      : outOrigin,
                        destination : outDestination
                    },
                    carriers : outCarriers
                }
            };

            // will display the NEW FORMAT OF DATA
            console.log( data );
        });
```

Anyone who worked on flight api would be easily knowing what i want to achieve

Comment: What have you tried? Hint; json_decode($json)

Comment: `$.each(itineraries, function( itineraryKey, itineraryVal ){
                    var inbound          = app.getObjects( legs, 'Id', itineraryVal.InboundLegId),
                        inOrigin        = app.getObjects( places, 'Id', inbound[0].DestinationStation),
                        inDestination   = app.getObjects( places, 'Id', inbound[0].OriginStation),
                        inCarriers      = app.getObjects( carriers, 'Id', inbound[0].OperatingCarriers[0]); `
                       i'm expecting something like this

Comment: please add your code into the question using the "edit" button (just below the little blue "javascript" and "php" tags"). Code in the comments like that is not very readable. Also please explain to us what that code produces now, and show us what you wanted it to produce instead. We cannot guess how you want your output to look. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. Friendly hint: "Please provide...as I'm facing deadline" is not a polite or good way to talk to people here. Please respect that we are _volunteers_ helping you in our spare time, for free. Your time is _not_ more valuable than ours, yet your sentence implies that we should all jump to it. If you're failing to meet a deadline that is not our problem, instead you maybe should improve your time management and / or ask for suitable support within your organisation. People will answer the question when they have time and inclination (but right now it's impossible without the full info)

Comment: @ADyson I'm very sorry for my way of asking question, i've edited my question

Comment: @Jadheer that's fine. I just wanted to help you for the future. I'm glad to see you edited it - thankyou. Now it would be great if you could provide us enough information to help solve your problem.

Comment: @ADyson i've edited my question, in that you can see that required data is brought into new format i' expecting something like it, if you still did not understand my question please feel free to ask.

Comment: ok thanks. So what is going wrong with your code? By the way I cannot see where it produces any HTML. It would make it easier for us to help you fix it if you can explain what is happening currently. Also please be clear about the input data - can we assume that `itineraries` is an array containing lots of the type of JSON object shown above? Or is it just that single object? P.S. It's comparatively unlikely that anyone answering a random JS question has worked on this specific API before, so you really need to explain it to us in detail.